# What is the name of contractors designing high power supplies with relay logic?

Tags: power-supply, relay

I have been designing a 3 phase power supply with distribution strip and redundant contactors with failure detection (I posted a question not long ago related to that, it's based on relay logic), and since we do not have related experience in my company I would like to hire a contractor to check and approve the design - perhaps finish it off and manufacture the units.

I have contacted various "electrical contractors" in the area, and they all responded saying it was beyond their expertise therefore I am starting to wonder if I have the right keywords.

Who would generally design such systems? It's basically just a very safe switchable 3 phase supply, what's so unique about that?

P.S: We are located in Oxfordshire, UK

Comment: How about "Power Systems Application Engineer" ...?

Comment: Please take this question to our EE.SE chat where customs for what's on-/off- topic are more relaxed.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: We have a chat?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about electrical/electronics design.

Comment: Well, it is still related to design. Many questions ask to "name" a component or other bits and pieces. But I can understand it is an unusual question.

Comment: "Panel Builder" appears to be the [UK term](http://www.amaresearch.co.uk/Panel_Builders_15.html) too.

Comment: @MisterMystère  [Yes, we have a chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)  Chats are StackExchange's best kept secret.

Comment: Excellent, thank you both. @Majenko: power systems engineering doesn't seem to pop any new interesting result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a panel builder / industrial automation OEM.  If you can't find anyone with those descriptions, look around for PLC Programming.  They generally fall into the same category.

I don't know anybody personally across the pond, but I'm certain there are a bunch of small OEM's that do motor drives, PLC's, and the associated panel work.

Comment: Good idea, I'm going to see what I can find.

Comment: I have very interesting results with "panel builder", that should do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sort of weird that I don't have a better name than that, but that is what I did for about 15 years before my current job.  We never came up with anything better either.